# Unable to connect remotely to mysql server via phpmyadmin using xampp in Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, phpmyadmin, xampp, remote-access

I have a problem where i can't connect to remote mysql server in Windows 7 using phpmyadmin in xampp v3.2.1. I'm trying to connect the database in the server from client PC. But I get the error.

I have added code in config.inc.php.

```html
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '10.190.121.192';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';
```

When I open localhost and choose the server IP address, I'm always get the same error eventhough I tried any solutions here and there.

The error appear:
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?